# "Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String" while performing a search

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Trying to search through a DataList, with the parameters being movie genres (loaded through a database, so no switch case) and a name

```
protected void ButtonFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filter = "";
        int selectedCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.CheckBoxListGenres.Items.Count; i++)
            if (this.CheckBoxListGenres.Items[i].Selected)
                selectedCount++;
        if (selectedCount > 0)
        {
            filter = "GenreID=";
            int n = 0; //Used to determine to which genre the loop has arrived
            for (int i = 0; i < this.CheckBoxListGenres.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (this.CheckBoxListGenres.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    if (n > 0 && n < selectedCount)
                        filter += " AND ";
                    filter+="'*"+this.CheckBoxListGenres.Items[i].Value.ToString()+"*'";
                    n++;

                }
            }

            if (this.TextBoxMovieName.Text!="")
                filter += " AND MovieName LIKE '*" + this.TextBoxMovieName.Text + "*'";
            DataTable dataTable = ((DataSet)Application["DataSetMovies"]).Tables[0];
            DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
            filter = Convert.ToString(filter);
            dataView.RowFilter = filter; //!Getting the error here!
            this.DataListMovies.DataSource = dataView;
            this.DataListMovies.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Tried debugging, the string itself seems fine, so I tried using Convert.ToString() on filter, just to make sure but it doesn't matter.
Help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you are trying to add a filter that checks if `GenreID='2'` or something, perhaps it is treating it as a string but the column is integer, try removing all the extraneous formatting and create a filter that just does `GenreID=2`. Can you provide an example of what `filter` contains when it is being set? Also as Igor points out, your chaining of `AND` expressions cannot just daisy chain values, you need to specify the field each time too: `GenreID=2 AND GenreID = 3`.

Comment: 1. Is your GenreID a text or nummeric field?
2. Have you tried to check filter expression before assigning? According to your code you can get GenreID='*AAA*' AND '*BBB*' AND '*CCC*' which is not valid expression

Comment: The error is not about ` filter` being a wrong type. The error is about the contents of ` filter` itself

Comment: @SonerGönül The error would be on that line if the exception was from the view trying to apply the filter.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth That's make sense surely. I thought this is a compiler time error rather than runtime.

Comment: @Acesii Please post an example of what `filter` contains just before you try to set it to the data view. It is very likely incorrectly formed. Please see: http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not compile time error this is runtime error.

Well in your database the thing for which you are applying filter is type of Int32..

For example if you have something like `Num` and it is of `Int32` but you do somthing like below :-

```
dv.RowFilter = "Num = '7097'" ////This will have error
```

It will throw error because it will require :-

```
dv.RowFilter = "Num = 7097" ////This is correct
```

So in your case you have `GenreID` which is of Int32 but in your code you are providing some string against it.

Comment: This error can also occur simply because the length of the variable ('7097') exceeds the string length allowed in the column ('Num') in the DataTable - I have tested this.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your GenreID column is an `INTEGER` and you're comparing it with a `STRING` as in `'**'`. In this sample I used the `IN`operator to list all values at once without the AND operator between them, what would cause a logic error as none items would have GenreID=1 and GenreID=2:

```
protected void ButtonFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filter = "1=1";
    if (this.CheckBoxListGenres.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Any(i => i.Selected))
        filter += String.Format(" AND GenreID IN ({0})'",
            String.Join(",", this.CheckBoxListGenres.Items.OfType<ListItem>()
                .Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Value)));

    if (this.TextBoxMovieName.Text != "")
        filter += " AND MovieName LIKE '%" + this.TextBoxMovieName.Text + "%'";

    DataTable dataTable = ((DataSet)MediaTypeNames.Application["DataSetMovies"]).Tables[0];
    DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
    dataView.RowFilter = filter;
    DataListMovies.DataSource = dataView;
    DataListMovies.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter in your condition might be invalid so Use `OR` at the place of `AND`

> Use `%` , insted of `*` in `LIKE` Operator
>
> I.E `filter += " AND MovieName LIKE '%" + this.TextBoxMovieName.Text + "%'";`

```
protected void ButtonFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filter = "";
        int selectedCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.CheckBoxListGenres.Items.Count; i++)
            if (this.CheckBoxListGenres.Items[i].Selected)
                selectedCount++;
        if (selectedCount > 0)
        {
            filter = "GenreID=";
            int n = 0; //Used to determine to which genre the loop has arrived
            for (int i = 0; i < this.CheckBoxListGenres.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (this.CheckBoxListGenres.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    if (n > 0 && n < selectedCount)
                        filter += " OR ";
                    filter+="'%"+this.CheckBoxListGenres.Items[i].Value.ToString()+"%'";
                    n++;

                }
            }

            if (this.TextBoxMovieName.Text!="")
                filter += " OR MovieName LIKE '%" + this.TextBoxMovieName.Text + "%'";
            DataTable dataTable = ((DataSet)Application["DataSetMovies"]).Tables[0];
            DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
            filter = Convert.ToString(filter);
            dataView.RowFilter = filter;
            this.DataListMovies.DataSource = dataView;
            this.DataListMovies.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `*` and `%` can be used interchangeably: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Search works with OR now, thanks (at least with the criteria I've put)

Answer (score 0):

`DataRow filteredRows = dt.Select(“Name LIKE '%” + searchstring + “%’`

OR

```
convert(Age, System.String) like '%” + searchstring + “%'”);
```

It works for me